# Vafa's semi-Ricci flat metric

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry

[Cumrun Vafa](https://www.physics.harvard.edu/people/facpages/vafa) with Greene-Shapere-Yau introduced semi-Ricci flat metric here

B. Greene, A. Shapere, C. Vafa, and S.-T. Yau. Stringy cosmic strings and
noncompact Calabi-Yau manifolds. Nuclear Physics B, 337(1):1–36, 1990

I know that such metrics are Kahler in fiber direction. Is there any counter example to show that such metrics are not Kahler in horizontal direction?

Comment: This is essentially the Gibbons-Hawking ansatz, why do you expect this is not Kahler?

Comment: This question has been solved in the affirmative by Y-J Choi in http://arxiv.org/abs/1508.00323

Comment: Which page? I couldn't find

Comment: Theorem 1.1 (iii)

Comment: @YangMills , see page 5, Satz 1, http://archiv.ub.uni-marburg.de/diss/z2015/0401/pdf/dmb.pdf

Comment: That's nice, thanks. This dissertation was announced a while ago in http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.2930, see footnote on p.7, and I was wondering what happened to it.

Comment: There is another proof of Berman via relative Kahler Ricci flow. see theorems 14,and 15 http://arxiv.org/abs/1002.3717. In fact due to Song-Tian and Tsuji, such flows always have solution and RKRF is not additional assuption.

Comment: I do not see how to derive the main theorem of Choi from that paper of Berman.

Comment: The paper of Choi turned out to be wrong, the thesis of Braun does not prove at all that the semi-Ricci flat form is semipositive, and neither does the paper of Berman. As far as I know, the question you ask is still unsolved.

Comment: with some mild singularity condition on central fiber, the computation of Choi can be revised . There is two thing, semi-positivity and smoothness. the semi-poitivity part is correct,

Comment: some authors also used this semi-flat metric as reference metric for Kahler Ricci flow $e^{-t}\omega_0+(1-e^{-t})\omega_{SF} $to solve boundedness of scalar curvature or GH limit,... along conical KRF, or KRF but this type of reference metric does not sit in KRF, and that papers are wrong.

Comment: Some people wanted to get twisted Kahler-Einstein metric by using a measure constructed by this semi flat metric, let me be bright, that type of metrics never can be twisted globally. They are twisted locally. so finding twisted KE metric is misleading . or some people wrote funny papers with some inequalities of high school to claim that they have fond a canonical metric when total space and fibers are CY.

Comment: what are the funny papers with inequalities of high school?

Answer (score 1):

A counterexample to the semipositivity of these semi-flat metrics (on elliptic $K3$ surfaces) was constructed by Cao, Guenancia, Paun, Tosatti in [this paper,](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.08087.pdf) see Theorem 3.1 and the Appendix.